# In Scala, how to get the ANSI display length of a String?

Tags: string, scala, ansi-escape

This is an minimalistic example:

```
  it("actual length") {

    import scala.io.AnsiColor
    val str = AnsiColor.RED + "c" + AnsiColor.RESET

    assert(str.length == 1)
  }
```

But when this test is executed, it shows that the length of the str is 10, while the display length of it should be 1 (all ANSI escape characters should have 0 length)

How to correct it?

Comment: @ AnsiColor.RED + "c" + AnsiColor.RESET
res6: String = "\u001b[31mc\u001b[0m"

@ res6.length
res7: Int = 10

you litterally send all 10 bytes to the terminal, the interpretation of this (via terminal) shows you red 'c'. You can save this to file, it still 10 bytes. You can print it on paper. Depends on printer model/driver, it could print you red 'c' or raw "\u001b[31mc\u001b[0m".

Comment: Sorry so I was wrong about the definition of length. Is there a way to get the display length instead of the binary size?

Comment: revised based on your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The [`length`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#length()) method's doc says this actually counts the number of [Unicode code units](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#unicode):

> In the Java SE API documentation, *Unicode code point* is used for
> character values in the range between U+0000 and U+10FFFF, and *Unicode
> code unit* is used for 16-bit char values that are code units of the
> UTF-16 encoding.

```
   /**
     * Returns the length of this string.
     * The length is equal to the number of Unicode code units in the string.
     *
     * Returns the length of the sequence of characters represented by this object.
     */
    public int length() {
        return value.length >> coder();
    }
```

There is no built-in solution to count what you want, but you can simply remove them with a regex. `AnsiColor` escape codes seems to have a precise pattern: `\u001b` + `[` + `1-2 digits` + `m`

```
  val str: String = AnsiColor.RED + "c" + AnsiColor.RESET
  println(str.replaceAll("\\u001B\\[\\d{1,2}m", "").length) // 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer is correct if only colour codes are involved, there are just more cases

Comment: you are going to have to expand the regex then

Comment: It should exist, just no one knows exactly what it is, or if it is OS/environment-agnostic

Comment: Yes, the ANSI escape codes seem to be [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), although, there seem to be extensions sets, so there are more colors than in `AnsiColor.java`.